# Mysql's LIKE is missbehaving with Hebrew and backslashes, why?

Tags: sql, mysql, utf-8, hebrew

I have the following SQL query which returns the correct results:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tags`
WHERE tag_name = 'בית\\\"ר-ירושלים'
```

If I change it to

```
SELECT *
FROM `tags`
WHERE tag_name LIKE 'בית\\\"ר-ירושלים'
```

or to

```
SELECT *
FROM `tags`
WHERE tag_name LIKE 'בית\\\"ר-ירושלים%'
```

It doesn't work. It will work if I remove all the backslashes and " from the query.

Comment: Check here maybe you can find the solution http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46659

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @halocursed said - this is a bug in MySql.
[bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46659](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46659)